# Why the navigation component has crashed when I want to navigate from two screen to same screen

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have three screens: CategoryScreen, CompanyScreen, and ProductsScreen.

I want to navigate from CategoryScreen and CompanyScreen to ProductsScreen.(ProductsScreen is a Common destination).

When I navigate from CompanyScreen everything is correct but when I want to navigate from CategoryScreen, the app is crashed.

[image]

**My NavHost:**

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        homeGraph(
            windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
            navigateToSubCategories = { navController.navigate(route = "${SubCategoryDestination.destination}/$this") },
            navigateToAllCategories = { navController.navigate(route = AllCategoriesDestination.destination) },
            nestedGraphs = {
                allCategoriesGraph(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
                    onBackClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                    navigateToProducts = {
                        navController.navigate(route = "${AllProductsDestination.destination}/$this/${ProductsType.CATEGORY.type}")
                    },
                    nestedGraphs = {
                        allProductsGraph(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
                            onBackClick = {},
                            navigateToProductDetail = {
                                navController.navigate(ProductDetailDestination.route)
                            },
                            nestedGraphs = {
                                productDetailGraph()
                            })
                    })
            }
        )

        allCompaniesGraph(
            windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
            navigateToProducts = { navController.navigate( route = "${AllProductsDestination.destination}/$this/${ProductsType.COMPANY.type}") },
            nestedGraphs = {
                allProductsGraph(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
                    onBackClick = {},
                    navigateToProductDetail = {
                        navController.navigate(ProductDetailDestination.route)
                    },
                    nestedGraphs = {
                        productDetailGraph()
                    })
            }
        )
    }
```

**CompanyNavigation file:**

```
object AllCompaniesDestination : IFishoppingNavigationDestination {
    override val route: String
        get() = "all_companies_route"
    override val destination: String
        get() = "all_companies_destination"
}

@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun NavGraphBuilder.allCompaniesGraph(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    navigateToProducts: String.() -> Unit,
    nestedGraphs: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit,
) {
    navigation(route = AllCompaniesDestination.route,
        startDestination = AllCompaniesDestination.destination) {
        composable(route = AllCompaniesDestination.destination) {
            CompaniesScreen(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
                navigateToProducts = navigateToProducts)
        }
        nestedGraphs()
    }
}
```

**CategoryNavigation fule:**

```
object AllCategoriesDestination : IFishoppingNavigationDestination {
    override val route: String
        get() = "all_categories_route"
    override val destination: String
        get() = "all_categories_destination"
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun NavGraphBuilder.allCategoriesGraph(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    navigateToProducts: String.() -> Unit,
    nestedGraphs: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit,
) {
    navigation(
        route = AllCategoriesDestination.route,
        startDestination = AllCategoriesDestination.destination
    ) {
        composable(route = AllCategoriesDestination.destination) {
            AllCategoriesScreen(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass,
                onBackClick = {},
                navigateToProducts = { navigateToProducts() })
        }
        nestedGraphs()
    }
}
```

**ProductNavigation file (common destination):**

```
object AllProductsDestination : IFishoppingNavigationDestination {
    override val route: String
        get() = "all_products_route"
    override val destination: String
        get() = "all_products_destination"
    const val allProductsArg = "allProductsParam"
    const val allProductsRequestTypeArg = "allProductsRequestTypeParam"
}

@ExperimentalLayoutApi
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun NavGraphBuilder.allProductsGraph(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    navigateToProductDetail: String.() -> Unit,
    nestedGraphs: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit,
) {
    navigation(route = AllProductsDestination.route,
        startDestination = AllProductsDestination.destination)
    {
        composable(route = AllProductsDestination.destination
            .plus("/{${AllProductsDestination.allProductsArg}}")
            .plus("/{${AllProductsDestination.allProductsRequestTypeArg}}"),
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(AllProductsDestination.allProductsArg) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(AllProductsDestination.allProductsRequestTypeArg) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )) {
            ProductsScreen(windowSizeClass = windowSizeClass, onBackClick = onBackClick)
        }
        nestedGraphs()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to navigate to a destination that’s not part of the nested graph